# How to change the color of matplotlib AxisSubplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering how to change the color of matplotlib `AxisSubplot` object.

Here is the MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = sns.load_dataset('iris')


p = df.hist('sepal_length',by='species',layout=(3,1))
p[0].set(title='Changed')
p[0].set(facecolor='b')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

## Type

```
print(type(p[0])
matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot
```

## My output

[image]

## Required

I want the color of histogram to be blue, not the background.

```
p[0] ==> red
p[1] ==> green
p[2] ==> blue
something like
p[0].set_color('r')
p[1].set_color('g')
p[2].set_color('b')
```

Comment: why did you draw histogram using pandas?

Comment: I would like matplotlib hist, but most of the time I am already using pandas and like to make quick and dirty plots with pandas and seaborn, matplotlib is the last resort.

Comment: You're asking how to change the color of matplotlib AxisSubplot - but you know that already - `ax.set(facecolor='b')`. Rather it seems you want to change the color of the bars, `df.hist(..., color="b")`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that would make all plots blue, I even tried `color=list('rgb')` which does not give three colors.

Comment: Oh, each histogram should have a different color, right? Then probably you need to create each one separately and supply the respective color.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thanks for the suggestion, I know that,  I can do that easily with three plt.hist(). I was thingking if there was method available for Axissubplot.

Comment: `AxesSubplot` is just the axes. It's the object you get when calling `plt.subplot(111)`. Since the axes doesn't know about its content, there is no general method to make the axes content blue. You can however set all patches within an axes to blue, like `plt.setp(ax.patches, color="blue")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

n_unq = df['species'].nunique()
colors = (list('rgbcmyk')*100)[:n_unq]

xmin = np.min(df['sepal_length'])
xmax = np.max(df['sepal_length'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(n_unq,1,figsize=(12,8))

for i, (label,grp) in enumerate(df.groupby('species')):
    series = grp['sepal_length']
    p = series.hist(ax=ax[i],color=colors[i],label=label)
    p.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax))
    p.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Gives:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've done it using `seaborn`'s `distplot`, first i've found unique strings in the `species` column, for each of them, i draw a distinct histogram in each subplot based on `sepal_length`. as you can see i set the color of first histogram to be **Blue**, and the remaining plots are **Red** !

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

unique_species = np.unique(df['species'])
for i in range(len(unique_species)):
    plt.subplot(1,len(unique_species),i+1)
    temp = df.loc[np.where(df['species']==unique_species[i])]
    if i == 0 :
        sns.distplot(temp['sepal_length'],bins=10,kde=False,rug=False,color='b')
    else:
        sns.distplot(temp['sepal_length'],bins=10,kde=False,rug=False,color='r')
    plt.title(unique_species[i])
plt.show()
```

the resulting plot would be :

[image]